# Are they all legal cc videos?

Tags: legal

I chose a video from "A"'s channel which was a cc video. Later on, I found that the video was not actually a cc video. "A" downloaded the video from "B" 's channel & introduced the video as a cc video. Now on good faith considering it a cc video, I uploaded it from "A" 's channel. Now...if "A" 's video channel is terminated for violation of youtube policy for this illegal practice will it be harmful to me??..

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking. By "CC" do you mean Creative Commons or Closed Captioning? I understand you are trying to anonymize things, but could you explain your situation more? Is this related to producing a derivative work or exhibiting the work? The former is on topic here but the latter is off topic.

Comment: I think the CC-2017 means adobe Creative cloud 2017. Perhaps the tag needs renaming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about legal advise, not video production.

Comment: We aren't well equipped to handle legal questions here, but there is a law SE that you might be able to ask it on.  Almost certainly you don't have the right to use the content that was incorrectly attributed as CC as they couldn't grant you a license, for the same reason I can't sell you my neighbor's house.  Even if you paid me for their house, you still wouldn't own it because it wasn't mine to sell.  There will probably be other finer points based on your local law though, so I'd still ask elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a copyrights lawyer, but I think you can consider your use of the video just as much a violation as 'A's version. 
When someone claims the rights to YouTube, you will also receive a notice and the video will be deleted.